# Is $\Pr[X \leq x] \leq \max(\Pr[X + Y \leq x], \Pr[X - Y\leq x])$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables which can be arbitrarily dependent. Does the following inequality hold:
\begin{equation}
\Pr[X \leq x] \leq \max(\Pr[X + Y \leq x], \Pr[X - Y\leq x]).
\end{equation}

The inequality seems trivial, but how can one prove this?

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that $\text{Pr}[X\leq x]\leq\text{Pr}(\max\{X+Y , X-Y\} \leq x)$, it is not true that it is less than the maximum of the probabilities.

Counterexample: Take $X$ and $Y$ to be standard normals and $x$ to be less than $0$.

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in your notation, did you mean $\max\{X + Y, X - Y\} \le x$?

Comment: Yes I did, thanks.

Comment: I don't think this inequality holds. Note that $\max\{X + Y, X - Y\} = X + \max\{Y, -Y\} = X + |Y|$, so the inequality holds in the other direction: $P(X \le x) \ge P(X + |Y| \le x)$.

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking for some reason silly reason that because the event that $max\{X+Y, X-Y\}\leq x$ was contained in the event $X \leq x$ that it had a greater probability, but of course this means it has a smaller probability.